# Office 365 - Default Style Update for Lists

Tags: styles, numbering, list, bullets, microsoft-word-365

I have searched all over and have not found a working solution.

I am trying to adjust the number list and bullet lists with less indent spacing. I have tried a number of different methods (from all over the web, including Stack Exchange) to do this but every time I attempt it the default 0.5 indent by returns.

Using: Microsoft Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13.628.20318) 64-bit

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which OS you are using. Also, saying "I have tried a number of different methods (from all over the web, including Stack Exchange) to do this" does not really tell us what you have already tried. You will get better responses telling which methods you have tried (possibly with links).

Answer (score 0):

### You should attach your numbering and bullets to existing paragraph styles using the Define New MultiLevel List Dialog.

Here are two reference pages on this:

- Windows - [Shauna Kelley's page](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)
- Mac - [John Korchok's page](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/)

Shauna Kelly has an [additional page on bullets](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html).

Once you have this set up, you apply the bullets or numbering by applying the relevant styles, not using the icons on the Ribbon. You change the indents in the Define New MultiLevel List dialog, not in paragraph formatting nor in the paragraph style, nor using the Ruler.

The list style, itself, is never directly used. It holds the definitions, but the numbering or bullets are applied by applying the styles. It is possible to assign keyboard shortcuts to your styles. Here is a link to [my article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) on the Microsoft Answers site on how to do this.